# Testing if a server is up with curl and grep. Grep adds headings?

Tags: curl, grep

Hi I'm trying to see if a server I'm running has been stopped (if it has, it returns a 502 Bad Gateway message.)

So I tried to do this :

```
curl http://MY_URL | grep "502"
```

The curl part returns what I expect it to.

But when I pipe it into grep, grep seems to be adding a bunch of headings :

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
113   682  113   682    0     0   230k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  666k
```

These aren't in the output from curl. And grep on ordinary text files doesn't add them. So why are they getting added to curl piped through grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That output *is* from `curl`. It's added when standard output is not a terminal, and in some other circumstances. Use `curl -s` if you don't want to see it.

Comment: Weird behaviour though, isn't it? To produce different output depending on whether it's going to the terminal or stdout. I thought unix tools were meant to ignore that kind of context.

Comment: Don't ask me, I didn't write it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a grep proble, but a curl *feature*. Try it with cat and you will see.

You can deal around it with -s (suppress the progress meter), an *-o output* .

**Man curl** for more.